# Resize table columns using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to implement resizable table columns, such that when you click and drag on a "notch" on the right side of the `th` (just a styled div inside the `th`), a new "marquee" element is created inside the `th` and displayed as a guide for resizing. On mouseup, the marquee disappears and the `th` element's width is set to the new width.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Bd/2/) to illustrate.

It seems like the answer is to create a directive, but my main hangup is how to handle the dynamically-added window mousemove listener plus the "one" window mouseup listener within the directive logic.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how to handle". You already have a working solution, don't you?

Comment: My understanding is that the OP would like to know how to convert the solution he has into Angular, most probably using a directive.

Comment: Place your fiddle in the postLink callback of a directive. Calls like `$th.width()` won't work unless the table is already visible in the DOM. If the directive is using a template to create the table. You might have to use `$timeout`. Otherwise, I don't see anything in your fiddle that can be done in a directive.

Comment: @MichalCharemza thanks for editing and clarifying, that is what I am looking for. Mathew Foscarini thanks for the insight. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Can we do something.. user can't resize the column less then the coloumn content width

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your question is about the "marquee", that is shown for the resize. The solution to this problem is using `$scope.$apply`, which is responsible for notifying about change of the resize automatically to DOM HTML. Check out `mousemove(e)`.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Bd/31/